# How can I resolve the issue of app crashes On Button click?

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio

Whenever I press second button(fireb) my app crashes. However first button(click) is working fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button click;

    public  static TextView data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        data = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fetcheddata);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                fetchData process = new fetchData();

                process.execute();

            }

        });

        Button fireb =(Button) findViewById(R.id.fire);

        fireb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Member go = new Member();

                go.execute();
                DatabaseReference reff;
                reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");
                reff.push().setValue(go);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Data Inserted Sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

Actually I want to execute the class "Member" with object "go" and then want to post that data contained in "go" to firebase database .

Here is the crash log....

```
--------- beginning of crash
05-11 14:35:51.301 3457-3457/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 3457
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid key: . Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validateWritableKey(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:120)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validateWritableObject(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:103)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:283)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.3.0:159)
        at com.example.myapplication.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:51)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
05-11 14:36:01.830 3457-3472/? I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17161(834KB) AllocSpace objects, 9(611KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 3MB/5MB, paused 545us total 172.404ms
05-11 14:36:05.223 3457-3457/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3457 SIG: 9
```

And here is the Member class.

```
public class Member extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String mdata = "";
    String ad_id = "";
    String price = "";
    String username = "";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {
                   .
                   . 
                   .
            JSONObject JO1 = new JSONObject(mdata);
            JSONObject JO2 = JO1.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray JA = JO2.getJSONArray("ad_list");
            JSONObject JO3 = JA.getJSONObject(0);
            JSONObject JO4 = JO3.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONObject JO5 = JO4.getJSONObject("profile");

            username = (JO5.getString("username")).trim();
            ad_id = JO4.getString("ad_id").trim();
            price = JO4.getString("temp_price").trim();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

}
```

May be it is easy but I am developing my first app:)

Comment: Try debugging your code. It will allow you to deeper understand how it works and where is the problem.

Comment: The error message says: "Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'". This means that you have one of these non-allowed characters in a path that you're trying to write to the database, specifically on line 51 of MainActivity.java. Most likely your `public class Member extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {` generates a disallowed character somewhere. That `extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {` is very unusual in interacting with a database, and I'd highly recommend separating the `AsyncTask` from the data that is written to/read from the database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I just need solution at this point

Comment: As said  I'd highly recommend separating the `AsyncTask` from the data that is written to/read from the database. Or just create a `Map` with the four members of `Member`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to firebase as showing in logs.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you setValue with:

> Invalid key: . Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']

But after looking at your code, there is something that I can't understand.

```
            go.execute();
            DatabaseReference reff;
            reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Member");
            reff.push().setValue(go);
```

You do AsyncTask, and you don't listen to the result.

Comment: I can remove that from my code if need. I just want to post that to firebase anyhow. It will be great if you can suggest me the fix.